# Bootmenu not appeared at boot time

Tags: 11.10

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 along side with Win7.
but it is not showing Operating System select option at boot time, instead it boots to Win7 directly.
can anyone help me...

Comment: Did you install windows or linux first? Do you have Windows and Linux on the same hard drive? If you installed Windows after Linux it might have overridden your boot loader, then you have to reinstall it from within a live cd.In the latter case, your bootloader might be installed on the other hard drive, then you should select the other hard disk as boot device in your BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to enter a key combination.  Try holding Shift-F8 or F8 alone just after your BIOS screen goes away and before the 'loading windows' screen comes up.  You'll have to have good timing, so try at least a few times.

After that you might need to configure the boot loader, but that appears to be beyond your immediate problem for now.

Comment: I dont think this helps, it will show the windows boot menue.

Comment: It may do that, but at least shows whether the Windows bootloader is taking over first or if it is a problem with grub selecting Windows by default without prompts.

Comment: You wont see the difference, as after grub passed the control to windows boot progress you can still press F8 to open the same windows boot menu.However, lets wait for Kartik.